# Why doesn't my keyboard work on boot

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

Why doesn't my keyboard work when the computer is booting? I can enter BIOS and change the settings, but when the system is booting it doesn't work at all! This is not a new problem, but I now want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but what if GRUB doesn't work and will always boot into Ubuntu? I have tried to put the USB keyboard in the other slots including those on the front.

Comment: Is there a "legacy USB" setting in your BIOS?

Comment: But I have an old BIOS menu, and I don't know where that is.

Comment: OK I found an entry named USB keyboard function. I enable it and it's the same. why?

Comment: oh, for some reason it's working now, thanks for the help!